# Self editing script

Tags: python

I am designing a program in python that i want to send keystrokes between the numbers in the code code posted down below on repeat until stopped. The script uses the keyboard import to type but i cant seem to get it to type the randomly generated number. i have tried making it self edit but it has done absolutely nothing at all. It is supposed to be a bruteforce program supposed to be able to brute force anycode with just a quick edit to the digit amount.code:

```
while (0 < 3):
    import keyboard
    import random
    import re
    import time

    keyboard.write('')
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
    time.sleep(1)
    number = random.randint(00000,100000)
    print("trying ",number)


    rewrite_txt ='"keyboard.write(' + str(number) + ')"'
    newcode=compile(rewrite_txt,"",'exec')
    eval(newcode)
```

Comment: The behavior your desire and the behavior in its current state are unclear. Also, it's a lot better if you don't import your modules in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do given the context clues:

```
import keyboard
import random
import re
import time

while (0 < 3):
    number = random.randint(0,100000)
    keyboard.write(number)
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
    print("trying ",number)
    time.sleep(1)


    rewrite_txt ='"keyboard.write(' + str(number) + ')"'
    newcode=compile(rewrite_txt,"",'exec')
    eval(newcode)
```

Do your import outside of the while loop. Your `keyboard.write('')` call does nothing since you're passing an empty string. I assume you would like for it to write the `number`, so you should pass `number`. I would also say, if you want to brute force something, why are you using a random number? It will produce the same numbers multiple times. I would suggest the following:

```
import keyboard
import random
import re
import time

for number in range(100_000):
    keyboard.write(number)
    keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
    print("trying ", number)
    time.sleep(1)


    rewrite_txt ='"keyboard.write(' + str(number) + ')"'
    newcode=compile(rewrite_txt,"",'exec')
    eval(newcode)
```

Comment: it did not work at all i got this error: Exception has occurred: TypeError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
'int' object is not iterable
  File "C:\Users\murph_000\OneDrive\Documents\import random.py", line 7, in <module> (Current frame)
    keyboard.write(number)